# Host existing windows service to Azure service fabric

Tags: azure, wcf, windows-services, azure-service-fabric

We have a WCF service which is hosted as a windows service with endpoints exposed over tcp. We need to migrate and host this on Azure Service fabric.
Would like to know which option within Service fabric would be better :
1. Stateless Service
2. Guest Executable

Also what are the steps to migrate the same.
Any pointers would be very useful.

Thanks
Avanti

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions are suitable for you,

***Guest Executable***: You can migrate the service *as-is* without code changes, the only work required will be configure it in the application within SF, configuration like exposing the ports used by the service, define startup parameters, and required settings.

***Stateless Service***: You need to write the hosting of the service using SF application model, this will make changes to the original solution and might add changes to other dependencies, like for example if the service has 32bit dlls that does not run on 64bit.

I would recommend you start moving it as a ***Guest Executable***, then move to ***Stateless Service*** in a later stage if you think you could make a better use of the platform features.

Regarding the guidance, you should be fine following the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app)